# Constrained or Constraint?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was sending a mail to a dealer regarding some issue, and I typed a letter, then my friend corrected it stating that I should use *Constraint* instead of *Constrained*.

The Context:

> While other dealers are waiving off LBT charges and also providing aforementioned freebies with many other when my colleagues approached for enquiry about the same. Therefore, I also expect the same scene else we may be **constraint** to change our mind to cancel the booking.

What should be used here? *Constraint* or *Constrained*?

Comment: The whole paragraph should be corrected. It is not just about the 2 words. One thing for sure is your friend doesn't know what he/she is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `constraint` is a restriction on something whereas something can be `constrained` to be within, or to comply with, a `constraint`.

In the text of the question the correct word of the two is `constrained`.

However, taking whole text into account neither word is really appropriate. Starting with

> Therefore, I also expect the same scene else we may be constraint to change our mind to cancel the booking.

Better words include `forced` and `obliged`. The word `deal` works better than `scene` for financial or commercial topics. `Otherwise` and `and` read better than `else` and `to`, respectively, in the sentence. Leading to:

> Therefore, I also expect the same deal otherwise we may be forced to change our mind and cancel the booking.

Similar improvements might be made to the first sentence. Additionally, both sentences seem longer than necessary. Here are two alternatives:

> Other dealers were waiving off LBT charges and were also offering many freebies when my colleagues enquired about the same [product]. Therefore, we would expect a similar deal otherwise we may be forced to cancel our booking.

Or

> When my colleagues asked other dealers about the same [product], they were waiving off LBT charges and were also offering many freebies. Therefore, we would expect a similar deal otherwise we may be forced to cancel our booking.

I do not like the word `[product]` but not knowing the context I cannot think of a better word. Be careful about mixing "we" and "I".